# How not to break the inner spans in bootstrap 2.x on small screen

Tags: html, scaffolding, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have the below code  in the form.

```
<div class='row-fluid'>
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="span6">
            <div>
                <div class="span6">StartDate</div>
                <div class="span6">2015-10-01</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <div>
                <div class="span6">Class Staff</div>
                <div class="span6">Admin Staff</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the full screen it shows like below (which is as expected)

[image]

In the small screen it breaks like below even though there are enough space at right side.

[image]

What I need as below. I do not want to break the inner spans.

[image]

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: i think `span` is similar to `grid` columns and they are designed that way. If its a static text than use it in same `span` or if not than still you can do it via using `variables`.